# How to convert a String to an Array received from a html text box and then transfer it to a stored procedure?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, stored-procedures, jdbc

I receive the String in a text box( like: "Delhi,Mumbai,Kolkata") and then send it to a jsp page where i need to convert it to a Array so that first element of array has "Delhi", second has "Mumbai" and so on. Now I want to send this array to my database handler page where i have a method which needs to receive this string and calls the stored procedure with this parameter. 
Basically, I'm not sure how to convert the string to array and then pass it to a stored procedure. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
This is my jsp code:
String s_word= request.getParameter("Search_Word");
            session.setAttribute("ssword", s_word);
            String[] indnames = s_word.split(",");
//Here i don't know how to send indnames to the dbhandler page.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
My method in dbhandler.java
public static ResultSet zz(String[] a) {
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try {

            Connection con = getConnection();
            CallableStatement ps = con.prepareCall("{call zz1(?,?)}");
            ps.setArray(1,a);
            ps.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            ps.execute();

            rs = ((OracleCallableStatement) ps).getCursor(2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

Array needs to be received by the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi, Convert the array to string and send it to the servlet using either ajax or http request call

Comment: But the whole point is to convert my string to an array since that's what my stored procedure needs

Comment: s_word.split(","); will convert the string to string array, what is the error you are facing.

Comment: While clean and build process, I get an error in my zz method "incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to Array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out how it's done. 
In my dbhandler.java page under zz method, I added:

```
Connection con = getConnection();
ArrayDescriptor arr= ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_COLLECTION",con);
//Here ARRAY_COLLECTION is my array type.
Array array= new ARRAY(arr,con,a);
//'a' is my String[] variable
Callable statement= con.prepareCall("{call zz1(?,?)}");
ps.setArray(1, array);
.
.
.
and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String cities[] = stringVariable.split("");
```

This will convert the String with multiple cities into String Array of cities.

Comment: Thanks, did that. But do you know how to pass this array to a Java method?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the value to java class like below,

```
<jsp:useBean id="sample" scope="page" class="com.mellon.sample" /> // sample is java file name  

//-------now pass parameter indnames to your sample java file here sample is the class name and function_name is the method name.

sample.function_name(indnames);
```